# Product/(s) of the following reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, homework, reaction-mechanism

I was wondering what the product will be in the following reaction:
$$\ce{H3COOCH3 ->[\ce{H+}]} \:?$$

I was thinking about $\ce{CH3COOH}$  being a product but I do not know the mechanism.

Comment: This is a specific case of the general reaction of **acid-catalysed ester hydrolysis**, which should be discussed exhaustively in any good organic textbook. This reaction is closely related to base-catalysed ester hydrolysis, aka saponification. I think any detailed answer to this question is quite redundant, however hopefully giving you the name of the reaction will point you in the right direction.

Comment: My school text book unfortunately does not provide the reaction mechanism. :(

Comment: here's a good overview: [link](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/catalysis/hydrolyse.html)

Comment: Wrong answer/comment. Without water no hydrolysis will happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you're sure that the initial formula is $\ce{H3COOCH3}$** (and that's a big **if**), then I disagree with Richard's answer in comments. [$\ce{H3COOCH3}$ is dimethyl peroxide](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C690028&Units=SI). While peroxides are not the most stable of molecules, and decompose rapidly (often by oxidizing other compounds), they do not spontaneously transform in acid conditions.

If the formula were $\ce{H3C–COOCH3}$ (note the added C), then yes, it's be [acid-catalysed ester hydrolysis](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/catalysis/hydrolyse.html).

Comment: Whoa, totally missed that. Well spotted. I was mainly looking at the acetic acid product.